# Using the likert package to plot two or multiple groups in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, likert

I'm working with the `likert` package and I can produce grouped results. However, I can't figure out how can I work with two (or multiple) groups, i.e., grouping the results by two columns (sex and country)

In the wrong format, something like that

```
likert(ds[,3:7], grouping=ds[,1:2]) %>%  
  plot()
```

or:

```
likert(ds[,3:7], grouping=ds[,1]) %>%  
  plot() +
  facet_wrap(~country)
```

The desired result can be this one

[image: result1]

Or even better something like this one
[image: better result]

Data and codes are below

```
ds <-structure(list(sex_female = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                             1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                             2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                             1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("male", 
                                                                                                                 "female"), class = "factor"), country = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                     1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                     1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                     2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                     1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                     2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                     2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                     2L), .Label = c("br", "sp"), class = "factor"), eat1_c = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
                    eat2_c = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
                                         2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                         NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, NA, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                         1L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), eat3_c = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                                                                      3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 2L, 
                                                                                                                      1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                      1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                      1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                      3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                      1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                      1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1", 
                                                                                                                                                                      "2", "3"), class = "factor"), eat4_c = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "3"), class = "factor"), eat5_c = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "3"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")

library(likert)
likert(ds[,3:7], grouping=ds[,1]) %>%  
  plot()
```